# How to do fillna in row level

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, fillna

I have a dataframe - df1:

```
     id    text v_2
0  id_1  text_1   a
1  id_2  text_2   b
2  id_3  text_3   c
```

I want to expand the dataframe by creating duplicated rows with different values in certain columns (id, text) but keep the same for the rest (v_2, v_3, .... in the real data, I have till v_50 columns which i want to keep the same values from the original df1):

[image]

I tried to create one additional dataframe df2 from df1:

[image]

and concatenate df1 and df2 together using:
`add_df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=0, ignore_index=True)`

result:

[image]

I tried to replace the `Nan` value using `df.fillna(value=values)`, but I think it only works on column-level but not row-level

Answer (score 0):

First, import `string` library to get a list of alphabets, then do fillna in row-level with `df.at[<index-of-row>,<name-of-column>]` ([source](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.at.html)).

```py
import string
alphabets =  list(string.ascii_lowercase)
for i in range(len(add_df)):
  for j in add_df.columns:
    cell = add_df.at[i,j]
    if cell != cell: # if nan
      add_df.at[i,j] = alphabets[int(add_df.at[i,'id'].split('_')[1]) - 1]
add_df
```

Result:

[image: result]

---

**EDIT**

If you want to select rows conditioned on the values in other rows, just try  this way:

```py
data = dict()
for i in range(len(add_df)):
  if add_df.at[i,'id'].startswith('id'):
    data[add_df.at[i,'id']] = add_df.at[i,'v2']
  if add_df.at[i,'id'].startswith('aug'):
    add_df.at[i, 'v2'] = data[add_df.at[i,'id'].split('-')[2]]
add_df
```

The result will be:

[image: result 2]

Comment: Hi Jordy, thanks for the answer, but actually what i want is the second image i posted in the question. I want to fill `NaN` with the same value if they have the same `column: id` (all *id_1 have the same v_2 value, all *id_2 have the same, etc)

Comment: I see. Please take a look at the updated answer.

Comment: Hi Jordy, thanks for your answer again. but the example i gave is actually a toy dataset, in my real dataset i do not have the alphabets as value but all different strings, so i guess i cannot do it in this way. The main question is i would like to select rows conditioned on the values in other rows.

Comment: To do that, save it in dict value first like this `{'id_1': 'a', 'id_2': 'b', 'id_3': 'c'}`, then use it as a dict key to update specific value